# Finding a path in a graph by its hash value

Tags: graph-theory, cryptography, hash-function

Assume there is a graph $G = (V, E)$ and a hash function $H: V^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^m$. Given a path $p = (v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$ from the graph $G$, compute its hash value $H(p) = h_p$.

**Question:** Given only the value $h_p$ for any path in the graph (or any "non-path" in the graph), can one prove or disprove that the path exists in the graph?

**Possible solution:** Expand the graph $G$ into a (possibly) infinite Merkle tree considering every vertex in $V$ as the respective root of the tree (designate these $m_v$). Try to match the hash value $h_p$ with all of the $m_v$ trees. If at least one tree can authenticate the $h_p$ value, then the path exists.

*Remark:* A *non-path* would be a sequence of vertices that does not correspond to the edges in the graph.

Comment: How do you define the hash value $h_p$?

Comment: This is trivially possible if there are finitely many vertices, so I assume there is an infinite number of vertices - but in this case, there could be infinitely many paths of length $n$, how are you "given" all these hash values?

Comment: It's a finite graph. You are given the hash values in that you can define the hash function to solve the problem, if it helps. (@baharampuri) It's not trivially possible, since to turn a graph into a tree, (say the graph has a cycle) the resulting tree may be infinitely large.

Comment: What if the hash tells you all vertices are present. Wouldn't you need to show that your graph contains a hamilton path? At least in the case of simple non-backtracking paths...

Comment: Good observation @draks... That means that this problem looks like NP complete.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a finite graph, the answer is yes, because for fixed $n$ there is only a finite number of paths of length $n$ in the graph. For example, you can enumerate all $n$-tuples of distinct vertices in the graph, check whether they form a path, compute the hash value of that path if they do, and check if that hash occurs in your list of hashes.

Comment: Yes, that is the brute-force solution. Is there any other way, so that you do not have to enumerate all paths and hash them?

Comment: At this point you'd need to make the question more formal, I think. What are your exact requirements and what properties does the hash function have?